# In Ruby, use a function defined within a method

Tags: ruby, algorithm

As part of an exercise, I'm trying to implement the bubble sort algorithm in two different ways.

For the first part, I've implemented the bubble sort algorithm as an Array instance method as follows:

```
class Array
  def bubble_sort!
    sorted=false
    until sorted
      sorted=true
      for i in (0...self.length-1)
        if self[i]>self[i+1]
          self[i],self[i+1]=self[i+1],self[i]
          sorted=false
        end
      end
    end
    self
  end
end
```

so that, for example,

```
[5,2,4].bubble_sort!
```

returns [2,4,5]. The next part of the exercise is to modify the method so that it takes a block to perform the comparison:

```
[1, 3, 5].bubble_sort! { |num1, num2| num1 <=> num2 } #sort ascending
[1, 3, 5].bubble_sort! { |num1, num2| num2 <=> num1 } #sort descending
```

In order to not repeat myself, I've tried to implement this as follows:

```
class Array
  def bubble_sort!(&prc)
    if block_given?
      boolean_operator = Proc.new {|a,b| prc.call(a,b)==1}
    else
      boolean_operator = Proc.new {|a,b| a>b}
    end

    sorted=false
    until sorted
      sorted=true
      for i in (0...self.length-1)
        # if self[i]>self[i+1]
        if boolean_operator(self[i],self[i+1])
          self[i],self[i+1]=self[i+1],self[i]
          sorted=false
        end
      end
    end
    self
  end
```

However, if I try to test this with

```
p [5,2,4].bubble_sort! {|x,y| x<=>y}
```

I get the following error:

```
in `bubble_sort!': undefined method `boolean_operator' for [5, 2, 4]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

It seems like the "boolean_operator" is somehow not defined where it is invoked (also not if I remove the block in the input). I understand that Ruby doesn't have nested methods, but I thought that defining procs and lambdas within a method was possible?

Comment: Using a lambda is a little more concise: `boolean_operator = ->(a, b) { prc.(a,b)==1}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is you're treating the variable you've defined as a Proc like it's a method (on the Array class, hence the NoMethodError). The proper way to call the proc is as follows:

`boolean_operator.call(self[i],self[i+1])`

Comment: Additionally but separately, you could refactor this so the a certain block as a default argument and you won't need to set it inside the method with an `if...else` statement.

Comment: A shorthand for `.call()` is `.()`.

Comment: @KeithBennett You can also do `boolean_operator[...]`.

Comment: @tadman Yes, you can, but I don't recommend it.  That syntax is confusing and IMO should only be used when the lambda's behavior resembles something that would normally be done with `[]`, such as the lambda returned by my `accessor` method in https://github.com/keithrbennett/trick_bag/blob/master/lib/trick_bag/collections/collection_access.rb#L82-99.